# If $\sum x_i^2$ is convergent, what is the necessary and sufficient condition of $\sum x_iy_i$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum x_i^2$ is convergent, what is the necessary and sufficient condition of  $\sum x_iy_i$  is convergent?

In my view, about the necessary and sufficient condition of convergency, there is little results.  I'm very curious about whether there results have been forgetten or there is  not too many such results?

Comment: Do you know the sequence spaces $\ell^p$ and their inner product ?, it is related to that

Comment: But it is not clear whether you are talking about real or complex sequences

Comment: @Physor  it is real. I know a little $l^p$,  it is a example in functional  analysis. Is there suitable book for  $l^p$?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any books that specialize in that. Any functional analysis book though should treat it fairly. For your question there must be some condition on the numbers $y_i$, otherwise the answer is no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remark*
The result to prove is this:

Let $(y_i)$ be a sequence.  Then the following are equivalent:

$\bullet\qquad$ $\sum x_i y_i$ converges for all sequences $(x_i)$ such that $\sum x_i^2$ converges.

$\bullet\qquad$ $\sum y_i^2$ converges.

This should be found in any textbook in functional analysis.

---

**added**

The set $l^2$ of all sequences $(x_i)$ such that $\sum x_i^2$ converges is a Banach space.  Functional analysis textbooks may then (very easily) deduce the fact you want from the [Uniform Boundedness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) .  We can avoid that machinery in this special case by doing some calculations, as shown below, unfortunately producing a much longer proof.  (The argument below is an example of a "gliding hump" argument.)

I assume known that $\sum(1/n)$ diverges and $\sum(1/n^2)$ converges.

Let $(y_i)$ be a sequence.  We caim:
If [for all sequences $(x_i)$ if $\sum x_i^2$ converges then $\sum x_i y_i$ converges], then  $\sum y_i^2$ converges.  Let's do the case where all $y_i > 0$.  (The general case can be reduced to this case.)

Assume $\sum y_i^2$ diverges.  We claim there is a sequence $x_i$
such that $\sum x_i^2$ converges but $\sum x_i y_i$ diverges.

First note that $y_i \to 0$.  If not, there is $a > 0$ such that $y_i > a$ for infiniteley may $i$.  Choose $x_i = 0$ for most $i$, but let $x_i$ run through the values $1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots, 1/n,\dots$ for the $i$ with $y_i > a$.  Then $\sum x_i^2 = \sum (1/n^2)$ converges, but $\sum x_i y_i > \sum (a/n)$ so $\sum x_i y_i$ diverges.

Define integers $0 = a_0 \le a_1 < a_1 < a_2 < \cdots$ as follows:

Choose $a_1$ so that for all $i \ge a_1$ we have $y_i < 1$.

After $a_{n-1}$ has been chosen, choose $a_{n} > a_{n-1}$ so that
$$
1 < \sum_{a_{n-1} \le i < a_{n}} y_i^2 < 2 .
$$

Then define a sequence $x_i$ by:

\begin{align}
\text{for } a_0 \le i < a_1,\quad&\text{define } x_i = y_i,\\
\text{for } a_1 \le i < a_2,\quad&\text{define } x_i = \frac{y_i}{2},\\
\text{for } a_2 \le i < a_3,\quad&\text{define } x_i = \frac{y_i}{3},\\
\vdots& \\
\text{for } a_{n-1} \le i < a_n,\quad&\text{define } x_i = \frac{y_i}{n},\\
\vdots&
\end{align}

We clam that $\sum x_i y_i$ converges, but $\sum x_i^2$ converges .

If $n \ge 1$, for the block $a_{n-1} \le i < a_n$, we have
$$
\sum_{a_{n-1} \le i < a_n} x_i y_i =
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{a_{n-1} \le i < a_n} y_i^2 > \frac{1}{n}
$$
so adding all blocks we get $\sum x_i y_i$ diverges.

If $n \ge 2$, for the block $a_{n-1} \le i < a_n$ we have
$$
\sum_{a_{n-1} \le i < a_n} x_i^2 =
\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{a_{n-1} \le i < a_n} y_i^2 < \frac{2}{n^2} .
$$
Adding on the first block, and using the fact that $\sum (2/n^2)$ converges, we get: $\sum x_i^2$ converges.

Comment: Could you give a reference or proof?   Only from  $\sum y_i^2$ converges to $\sum x_i y_i$ converges I can proved, but fail to prove the inverse.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks very much.